# The origin of action of the scalar-tensor theory of gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, action

I just started a project on the scalar-tensor theory of gravity and read up few papers and books related to it. In most of the books the idea and need for this theory is explained and from there the action is written without discussing how one can get that. My question is what is the motivation behind writing such an action?

Comment: Consider including the formula for the action.

Comment: Do you mean the [Brans-Dicke theory?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brans%E2%80%93Dicke_theory)

Comment: Yes @ZachMcDargh , the same.